# can't get data from web worker

Tags: javascript, web, web-worker, worker

I have the following forEach:

```
hosts.forEach((host) => {
  filterByHost(host);
});
```

as you can see the forEach call the following method where I pretend to use a web worker

```
function filterByHost(host) {
  let sortedHost = [];
  const filterHost = data.filter((element) => element.host.includes(host));
  if (window.Worker) {
    const worker = new Worker('utils.js');

    worker.postMessage({ cmd: 'sortHost', filterHost });

    worker.onmessage = function (event) {
      switch (event.data.cmd) {
        case 'sortHost':
          servers = {
            ...servers,
            [host]: event.data.data,
          };
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

the code inside my utils.js file is the following:

```
self.addEventListener(
  'message',
  function (event) {
    switch (event.data.cmd) {
      case 'uniqueHosts':
        postMessage({ cmd: 'other', data: other(event.data.data) });
        break;
      case 'sortHost':
        postMessage({
          cmd: 'sortHost',
          data: sortHost(event.data.filterHost),
        });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  },
  false
);

function other(data) {
  return bla bla bla;
}

function sortHost(filterHost) {
  return filterHost.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.apdex < b.apdex) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.apdex > b.apdex) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
```

As you can see I trying to using a web worker in order to sort a big array of objects, and the worker works, it return a sorted array, but when I try to spread the results inside my servers I have and empty array, is like when the forEach call a the new Worker every thing is restarted and I can't find why

Comment: Your code as is throws `hosts is not defined`.  Please share a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Nothing is dealing with the asynchronicity of the process, how do you determine that `servers` whatever it is has been updated. Also, starting a whole webworker for a simple sort is not gonna help much, and starting more wirkers than available CPU cores will make them all slower.